# Android studio 4.1 emulator crash

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-studio-4.1

I just upgraded my android studio to 4.1 version:

[image]

And tried to run some project on this emulator:

[image]

And for some reason, this specific emulator is crashing my android studio, I have noticed that I am getting an error:

[image]

After reading about the subject, I uninstalled "Riot Vanguard" but it did not solve my problem.

**More info (and partially solving the problem ) can be found in "Update" at the bottom of the question.**

In addition, moments after my android studio will get closed I will get a windows blue screen (happens every time).

I didn't have this problem earlier with android studio below 4.1 version, why is this happening?

---

### Update (problem solved for others emulators)

I have run into the same problem on other emulators as well, but I could open those emulators so I could fix the problem:

### Solution 1

According to most threads that I have run into, You will need to disable or uninstall "Riot Vanguard":

Open task manager, go to the startup tab, right click on Riot Vanguard, and press disable

[image]

---

### Solution 2

If step 1 didn't fix the problem you may want to [enable developer mode](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options) on your emulator.
For some reason with android studio 4.1 android studio could not find the emulator (It will tell you that there are "No connected devices") without enabling the developer mode

**Before Android studio 4.1 version I didn't need to enable the developer mode to run projects on emulators and this is what solved the problem for other emulators for me.**

---

### **BUT**

Although I don't have any problems with other emulators at all I still  **can`t even open Pixel_3a_API_30c68 emulator without it crashing**

How can I fix this problem on the specific emulator?

---

### Update 2

The problem still occurs even After updating android studio to 4.1.1

[image]

Comment: I also can't run emulator in new AS :(. It worked standalone, but after selecting the boot option in IDE i'm only getting info: "Connecting to Emulator" and nothing else happens.... Well..first stable version of AS is (un)"stable" as usually :(... Waiting for hotfixes...

Comment: @Mkr I have updated my answer, maybe it can help you

Answer (score 3):

Without having "Riot Vanguard" I also could not run any emulator in Android Studio since I upgraded to version 4.1. After some hours I finally found out what caused the problem (in my case):

"Android SDK Tools" have been replaced by other SDK tools (which ?) and is obsolete now. As soon as I UNINSTALLED "Android SDK Tools" the emulator worked again.

[image: Android Studio 4.1 - SDK Manager]

Comment: Thank you for your help, In my case the android SDK tools are fine so I don't think this is my problem.

Comment: For me Settings app kept on crashing , when I clicked on Developer Options, uninstalling this really helped and I did not even have to restart the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

I would be interested to know if the java version makes a different.  I moved from Windows to Linux because of problems running the emulator.
Linux worked great until I moved to Android Studio 4.1.  So check java and it was version 11.  Changed to java8 and it worked straight first time.
Seem to remember there was a setting in Android Studio to set the SDK which I think was version 8. But can no longer find this in settings in Studio 4.1.

Comment: Nice answer, but I am currently using Java 8 so I don't think this is the problem in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Updating to the latest system image of the SDK helped me.